# Why won't local Firebase document delete function work while served version does?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Node.js backend deployed and running locally using >firebase serve (which I use for preliminary development).  I am able to add and update documents locally (using Postman to emulate an external REST API). The same is true up on my Firebase server. What does **not** work are my delete document routines when run locally.  They work fine when run against the server version in Google. (Note. the delete routines were working locally when I was running an earlier 8.x version of Node.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.7.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
    "firebase-client": "0.1.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^1.0.7",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2",
    "twilio": "^3.32.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My local env is Windows 7.  I am using Postman to invoke local and served versions and the logs for both are the same, showing no errors.

My local Node version is v10.16.0

Finally here is on of my delete routines.

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
var firebaseClient = require('firebase-client')
var moment = require('moment');

const serviceAccount = require("./myconfiguration Info");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "my db url"
});
var db = admin.firestore()
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
var sessionRef = db.collection('Sessions')

exports.clearSessions = async function(){
  const response = await sessionRef.get().then(snapshot=>{
    snapshot.forEach((doc=>{
      if (doc.exists){
        doc.ref.delete()
      }
    }))
    return true
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.error(err)
    console.log('return false')
    return false
  })
  console.log(response)
  return response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if this is the problem, but you are ignoring the promises returned from `delete()`.  The `clearSessions` will return before they are resolved.  It's not clear from your who code calls `clearSessions` or what happens after that, but if your program terminates after it returns, the work might not complete.  If you intend to call this from a cloud function, the work almost certainly will not complete before the function terminates, if the promises are not taking into account.

Also, you are using a slightly outdated version of firebase-admin.  Try upgrading it.

Comment: That was the issue. By returning doc.ref.delete() and then await(ing) that result at the end of the function, it took care of it. I was also able to remove the await at const response = await sessionRef. It was superfluous.